# FontAwesome in first Column of DataTables.net

Tags: datatables

I have placed a check box in the first column (zero) of my datatable. When the user selects the row, the check box switches icons, indicating that the row has been selected.

```css
tr td:first-child {
  text-align: center;
}
tr td:first-child:before {
  content: "\f096";
  /* fa-square-o */
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
tr.selected td:first-child:before {
  content: "\f046";
  /* fa-check-square-o */
}
```

The next stage is to capture another field in the row, and fire off a click event, this is what i'm having difficulty with. I'm using server side processing, using DataTables.net 1.9.4

In the past, I've used this method:

```js
 "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aoData) {
                 $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html('<a class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip"' +
                       ' onclick="ViewMessage(\'' + aoData[9] + '\');">' + "View" + '</a>');
}
```

however, I prefer using the FontAwesome icons.

***UPDATE***

Ok, so as recommended, I've created another function outside of the main DataTable :

```js
$("#tblMessageDate").on("click", "tr", function () {

    var iPos = oMessageDate.fnGetPosition(this);

    var aData = oMessageDate.fnGetData(iPos);

    var id = aData[9];

    ViewMessage(id);
});
```

This now works, If I select any column within the row, in the sense that it fires off the ViewMessage function. However, this doesn't replace the icon with the checked icon. But, I do still have the icon in the first column (zero). And this works. So, how can I limit the selection of only column zero, using the above function?

Comment: I'm unclear about the process here - user clicks row & icon changes, then you need to get another value from the row and do what?

Comment: So I need to call another method, with the value of a field from the row selected. I can do this using standard DataTables functionality, but I'm unclear how to achieve this using an Icon, which changes (ticked, not ticked) when the row is selected.

Comment: So I need the fnRowCallBack, to replicate the CSS rules, and fire off the onclick

Comment: `fnRowCallBack` is only called when you reload the datatable, so I think you'll have to do this in an external js function.